# CUDA error when using a spacy3 gpu model, but CUDA works fine with pytorch on the same system

Tags: nvidia-docker, spacy-3

I'm running a docker with gpu enabled (nvidia-docker), and CUDA 11.3 installed, as well as cupy.

I can use torch models with no issue. I can see that my gpu is used as it should be.

In python, spacy loads fine, the gpu seems activated, and I can load models with no problem:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> spacy.require_gpu()
True
>>> spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
<spacy.lang.en.English object at 0x7efb7ddd6fd0>
```

But when I try to actually use these models to analyze some text, I get this error:

```
CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`
```

From what I read in other posts this error is supposed to appear when you run out of memory, but in this case it happens immediatly, the gpu stays at 0% usage as far as I can tell.

Here is the full exception I get: https://pastebin.com/x8kECw7p.